# Visual Studio Error Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: vb.net

I always get the following error

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in VarsityMonitoringSystem.exe

Additional information: An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

A while ago my code was working but after I take a shower there goes the error again 
Sorry I am a beginner I don't understand much in visual studio

so I got 2 forms. loginform and homeform. it seems like the code in my loginform doesnt recognize the homeform

Here is sample code, when the login button is clicked it will run this command

```
 con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\VarsityMonitoringSystem\VarsityMonitoringSystem\LoginTesting.mdb"
con.Open()
Dim usercmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("select * from Accounts where [Username]='" & User.Text & "'", con)
Dim userrd As OleDbDataReader = usercmd.ExecuteReader
If (userrd.Read() = True) Then
    If Pass.Text = userrd("PasswordAcnt") Then
        MsgBox("login successful!")


        HomeForm.lblID.Text = userrd("ID")
        HomeForm.lblName.Text = userrd("FirstName") & " " & userrd("MI") & " " & userrd("LastName")
        HomeForm.lblGender.Text = userrd("Gender")
        HomeForm.lblPosition.Text = userrd("PositionAcnt")


        If userrd("Picture").ToString = "" Then
            HomeForm.PictureBox1.ImageLocation = defPic
        Else
            HomeForm.PictureBox1.ImageLocation = userrd("Picture").ToString
        End If



        HomeForm.txtID.Text = userrd("ID").ToString
        HomeForm.txtFName.Text = userrd("FirstName").ToString
        HomeForm.txtMI.Text = userrd("MI").ToString
        HomeForm.txtLName.Text = userrd("LastName").ToString
        HomeForm.txtDOB.Text = userrd("BirthMonth").ToString & " " & userrd("BirthDay").ToString & " " & userrd("BirthYear").ToString
        HomeForm.txtGender.Text = userrd("Gender").ToString
        HomeForm.txtStreet.Text = userrd("Street").ToString
        HomeForm.txtMunicipality.Text = userrd("Municipality").ToString
        HomeForm.txtCity.Text = userrd("City").ToString
        HomeForm.txtContact.Text = userrd("ContactNo").ToString
        HomeForm.txtPosition.Text = userrd("PositionAcnt").ToString
        HomeForm.txtEmail.Text = userrd("Email").ToString
        HomeForm.txtEmailAdd.Text = userrd("Email").ToString
        HomeForm.txtUsername.Text = userrd("Username").ToString
        If userrd("Picture").ToString = "" Then
            HomeForm.UploadPBox.ImageLocation = defPic
        Else
            HomeForm.UploadPBox.ImageLocation = userrd("Picture").ToString
        End If

        HomeForm.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    Else
        MsgBox("Wrong Password!")
        con.Close()
    End If

Else
    MsgBox("Username doesn't exist!")
    con.Close()
End If
```

I tried to delete this code and replace it with homeform.show() but still the error persist it wont recognize the homeform

Comment: Check if you have spelled correctly the names of your columns. If you have a typo there then you get that error message

Comment: i tried to delete all commands in that button and replace with only command Homeform.Show() but then that error still appears it wont recognize my homeform and i tried re checking the spelling but nothing is wrong

Comment: this error happened to me before i solved it by closing all my application but now it wont just work

Comment: At what line does the error occur?

Comment: it starts to error when im trying to call my homeform

Comment: I tried to disable my antivirus to see if it's trying to prevent my form from functioning right yet nothing works

Comment: I tried to create another form and from that form use button to call my homeform. yet when i try to click the button that error shows again

Comment: Can you show us the exact line of code that throws the error?

Comment: HomeForm.lblID.Text = userrd("ID")
                HomeForm.lblName.Text = userrd("FirstName") & " " & userrd("MI") & " " & userrd("LastName")
                HomeForm.lblGender.Text = userrd("Gender")
                HomeForm.lblPosition.Text = userrd("PositionAcnt")

Comment: every code that starts with homeform

Comment: Is this a bug from VS2012 can anybody help me pls

Answer (score 0):

I have generated the same setup as you have one my machine. The only way I can get your issue is when the database fields does not exist. So this has nothing to do with your Form.

So to solve this you need to go into your mbd file and make sure that the Columns that you are querying for are there.